# Help search book: girl inside a dark room?

Tags: story-identification, novel

Here's what I remember from a fantasy book I've read years ago:

There's this girl locked inside a dark room. As in, total darkness. And she doesn't remember how she got there in the first place (if I remember correctly). Sooo, there are creatures inside that room and she somehow befriended most of them. I'm not sure but I think a witch has been keeping her there.

Huuuge mental leap, and the girl turns out to be a shapeshifter (or is it an animagus?).

I remebered the excellence of how it was written because you can really feel what she felt like being all alone; with nothing to see, but hear only weird noises.

Comment: When did you read it, other than "years ago"?

Comment: No shapeshifting, but otherwise sounds like [The Tombs of Atuan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tombs_of_Atuan).

Comment: "Years ago" perhaps... 2010-2012. But the book might be older.

Comment: And its setting althroughout is just a dark room.